# How do I find out where this error is coming from?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, reporting

Working on a Laravel 8 project, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "" CONTEXT:  unnamed portal parameter $1 = '' (SQL: select * from "[subjects]" where "[subjects]"."id" =  and "[subjects]"."deleted_at" is null limit 1) {"userId":297,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 22P02): SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: \"\"\nCONTEXT:  unnamed portal parameter $1 = '' (SQL: select * from \"[subjects]\" where \"[subjects]\".\"id\" =  and \"[subjects]\".\"deleted_at\" is null limit 1) at /var/www/[dev_site]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712)\n[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 22P02): SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: \"\"\nCONTEXT:  unnamed portal parameter $1 = '' at /var/www/[dev_site]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:373)
```

This is obviously a query to access all the model values for [subjects] which is failing because the id being passed is not defined. Unfortunately, I don't know where this is being called from. It is called from multiple places and so the error is popping up in multiple pages but I cannot locate the exact code that is generating this error which is being generated by:

```
/var/www/[dev_site]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:373
```

In some places where it comes up in the log, it appears to have no effect on the functioning of the code. In other places it breaks the code. I've been seraching the code with no luck. Is there some way to tell what code is triggering the error in Connection.php?

Comment: you have to find a file outside `vendor`, maybe in `app`, so check the stack trace until you find one. It is also possible it is coming from a package, and that is going to be inside the `vendor` folder. This is basic debugging, we cannot do anything with a single one of trace

Comment: The problem was that there was no stack trace other than what I put in my post. See my comment in @Ivailo Tsanev post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

```
try {
    ... your code here
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
}
```

It will list all method calls leading to the error you're getting. Let's say you have a controller that does lots and lots of things, you can wrap the entire body of the controller in a try-catch block, and anything that is executed in it that throws an error will get caught.

```
class MyController
{
    public function myAction()
    {
        try {
           // lots
           // lots
           // and lots
           // of things
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }
}
```

If you have no idea where this error occurs, you can wrap the method in your database wrapper/facade class in a try-catch block, and send the entire trace/exception to your logger, instead of just the message. Just remember to re-throw the exception so it gets handled further down properly, instead of suppressing it.

Comment: I tried the try...catch on an entire class, but it gave mer an error on "public". However I used the try...catch on the portion of the method in .../Connection.php and it gave me the location of the code making the error.

Comment: You can alter vendor code, just don't forget to revert the changes. This is the way to go in cases like this, if you aren't logging errors on production.